# Тавтология частицы "было"

Tags: тавтология, частицы

Меня смущает повторение частицы "было", причём не только в одном предложении, но и следующем. Вот пример текста, в котором "было" не разделяется промежуточным предложением, в котором отсутствует данная частица: "Ни к первой, ни ко второй категории нашего героя нельзя **было** отнести. Из-за предостережений учителей и выродившихся на этой почве опасений, он всё равно **был** обуреваем сомнениями о своей подготовленности". Такие конструкции вызывают у меня лёгкий диссонанс, но всё становится хуже, когда та же частица повторяется в одном предложении Т_Т
Я понимаю, что, при желании, можно объединить частицу с глаголом и вместо "не было видно" получить "не проглядывало", однако бывают случаи, когда подобная замена не всегда работает, отчего и хочу узнать, возможно ли повторение частицы "было" не только через одно предложение, но и в следующем, и даже в том, где "было" уже один раз употреблено?

Comment: *когда та же частица повторяется в одном предложении* - примеры пожалуйста. Пока что никаких тавтологий не наблюдантся и причины вашего "диссонанса" непонятны.

Comment: И еще. В ваших примерах "было", насколько понимаю, не является частицей. В первом примере "нельзя было" - категория состояния, во втором "был" - вспомогательный глагол для образования составной формы страдательного залога.

Comment: Вот ещё один пример: "На это пока нельзя **было** ответить, но в процессе своих исследований всё же **были** сделаны интересные выводы". После вашего замечания меня заинтересовало различие между частицей и вспомогательным глаголом. Первое было употреблено в качестве частицы, когда как второе в форме глагола. Можно ли оставить предложение в том же виде, если части речи обоих "было" разные?

Comment: Могу подтвердить лишь то, что систематика частиц всё еще предмет для дискуссий. Но в ваших примерах "было" - не частицы. "Было" частица только в значении отмененного, незавершенного  или прерванного действия при глаголе в прошедшем времени. ***"Он было собрался жениться, но передумал", "начал было писать диссертацию, но не смог закончить"*** и подобных.

Comment: "На это пока нельзя было ответить" — здесь похоже на ошибку. "Пока" указывает на настоящее время, "было" можно опустить.

Comment: Возьмем предложение: «Тогда на это нельзя БЫЛО ответить, но в процессе исследований всё же БЫЛИ сделаны интересные выводы». Здесь было и были – вспомогательные глаголы, нет частиц  (было нельзя – форма вспомогательного глагола для модального слова «нельзя»).  Но в любом случае такой повтор нельзя приветствовать, при этом не имеет значение грамматика слова «было» (частица или вспомогательный глагол). Это стилистический недочет,  нужно МЕНЯТЬ предложение, например:   «Тогда это не могли объяснить, но в процессе  исследований всё же были сделаны интересные выводы».

Answer (score 0):

> Части́ца — служебная часть речи, которая вносит различные оттенки
> значения, эмоциональные оттенки в предложении или служит для
> образования форм слова.
> [[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_(%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8))]

В приведённом вами примере «было» и «был» не являются частицами.

---

В первом случае *«…героя нельзя было отнести»*: «было» — это вспомогательный глагол, который служит для образования страдательного залога.

> БЫТЬ...
>
> II. Как вспомогательный глагол:
>
> 2. Употребляется для образования сложных форм страдательного залога.
>
>    ```
>    Сад был посажен школьниками. Я был глубоко оскорблен словами гвардейского офицера. Пушкин, Капитанская дочка.
>    ```
>
> *[Малый академический словарь под редакцией Евгеньевой]*

---

Во втором случае *«…он всё равно был обуреваем сомнениями…»*: «был» — это связка.

> БЫТЬ...
>
> II...
>
> 1. Употребляется в значении связки между подлежащим и именным сказуемым (в настоящем времени, как правило, опускается, но в книжном
>    языке иногда употребляется 3 л. ед. и мн. ч.).
>
>    ```
>    Но, витязь, будь великодушен! Пушкин, Руслан и Людмила. Труд есть борьба человека с природою. Писарев, Зарождение культуры. [Лемм] был небольшого роста, сутуловат. Тургенев, Дворянское гнездо. Преподавание и учение суть средства образования. Л. Толстой, Воспитание и образование. [Маша:] Вы были тогда поручиком. Чехов, Три сестры. Возбуждение его [Рощина] было так велико, что он не чувствовал боли. А. Н. Толстой, Восемнадцатый год.
>    ```
>
> *[Малый академический словарь под редакцией Евгеньевой]*

---

> Тавтология (греч. ταυτολογία от ταύτό или λέγείν — говорить то же
> самое) — термин стилистики, означающей ненужное повторение. Особенно
> часто название Т. применяется там, где мы имеем дело с повторением
> слов одного корня...
>
> *[[Энциклопедический словарь Брокгауза и Ефрона](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%A1%D0%91%D0%95/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F)]*

В данной ситуации было и был не выражают одно и тоже, хотя и являются однокоренными. Поэтому такое употребление не тавтология.

Comment: Розенталь: Тавтология — повторение в предложении **однокоренных** слов.

Answer (score 0):

Слово "было" (и некоторые другие, например "сказал") — это слово-невидимка. Ничего страшного в его повторении нет, потому что в очень многих языках "быть" и "иметь", можно сказать, структурообразующие слова.

Но лучше, конечно, в литературном тексте избегать повторов. Один из самых простых способов удалить "быть" — это избавиться от страдательного залога: вместо *"он всё равно был обуреваем сомнениями"* написать *"его всё равно обуревали сомнения"*. В таком варианте мы получаем зияние *"...равн**о о**буревали...*, но в вашем случае это меньшее из зол.

Приведённый вами отрывок вообще трудно отнести к литературе, его можно (и нужно) править. Что значит *"выродившееся опасение"*? Почему *"сомнениями о..."*, хотя надо *"сомнениями в..."*? И так далее. Вот пример, как этот текст должен выглядеть, чтобы хоть немного походить на художественный (и заодно избавиться от двойного "быть"):

> Ни к первой, ни ко второй категории нашего героя отнести было нельзя.
> Учителя вечно его предостерегали и тем самым взрастили в нём целую
> колючую изгородь опасений. Теперь герой всерьёз сомневался: достаточно ли подготовлен?..

Или:

> Ни в первую, ни во вторую категорию наш герой не попадал. Из-за
> учителей, что непрестанно его предостерегали, он был весь полон
> опасений и обуреваем сомнениями: готов ли?..

Или ещё множество вариантов.